# Why is my 7-segment display not working when output modules (O3-O0) are connected to BCD to HEX converter module?

Tags: 7segmentdisplay, 8051, decoder

I have used an 8051 interfaced with an 8255 taking inputs from port A and port 1 and showing the output from port B AND C of the 8255. I also made a decoder for BCD to HEX (0-F). The input value is showing, but thr output value is having a problem.

[image: CALCULATOR]

Comment: Please just state the topic of your question in the title, and ask your question in the post body. The raster image looks generated by some design tool: please edit your question and tell which.

Comment: If I had to guess (and I do because I don't recognise the simulation software) those grey dots represent high impedance outputs ("tri stated").

Comment: `facing a problem` / `having some problem` On StackExchange, please describe problems with enough detail to provide a useful answer.

Comment: @greybeard _"Please just state the topic of your question in the title"_ That's a common misconception. See ['How to write a good title?'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/1148803).

Answer (score 1):

Not-so-wild guess about the grey square dots at outputs O0-O3 of the 8255A and the segment outputs of the hex-to-7-segment decoder:

Voltage levels in the forbidden region.
For outputs, this is between .4 Volts and 2.4 Volts.

All outputs annotated with a grey dot drive an LED's anode, cathode grounded:
(Your LEDs/7-segment displays don't shine blue (or white).)

With a 0 output they'd show blue for logical 0,
grey means logical 1, but not suitable to drive a TTL level input.

Proteus shows output voltages in the forbidden region that way as well as inputs in the forbidden/undefined region from .8 to 2 Volts.

You can try inserting a 560 Ohms resistor between output and LED (-display).

Comment: I have solved the grey dot problem there was some voltage drop but problem is in 7 segment display, when I connected it to input module(I0-I3/I4-I7) its showing values but connecting output modules(O3-O0) to 7 segment is not giving any values.